# как удалить строки из таблицы генерируемой ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть табл. отображение генерится через ajax

Результат вывожу в тег

```
 $("#table-devices-tbody").append(aaa);

                     aaa = aaa +
                    '<tr id=' + result[key].uuid + ' class="table-devices-tr">' +
                    '<td db_id="devType">' + buttonDevicesWithGoOver + window.deviceType + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + blinkerIn + '</td>'+ 
                    '<td>' + deviceStatus + '</td>' +  
                     '<td><span>' + result[key].device_info.name + '</span></td></tr>';
```

уже в готовой выдаче мне нужно убрать (скрыть) все строки по определенному типу

Пытался на кодить

```
$('#table-devices-tbody tr').each(function() {
var black;

window.uuidOfElement = $(this).attr('id');

  if ( $(this).find('td:eq(0)').attr('db_id').val() == window.deviceType_2832) {
    $("tr[id$='" + window.uuidOfElement + "']").css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table-devices-tbody tr').each(function() {
    var black,
        firstTd = $(this).find('td:eq(0)');

    if ( firstTd.attr('db_id').val() == window.deviceType_2832) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Как-то так, наверное

Comment: скрывает только содержимое столбцов (не всех) .